# Anylogic - how to refresh databases based on Excel on standalone application?

Tags: excel, database, anylogic

In my AnyLogic app, i have some databases linked with Excel files. I have done a standalone app for my client. It works properly. But, my client is still using the Excel file in which he can change some data. In the standalone app that i have created for him, the databases contain a picture of the values of the Excel files, the day of the export. I don't want my client to set the values at the beginning of the optimization. I would like to simplify his life an try to use the Excel files that contain all the information’s needed. But, i don't know how to do it. Can you help me ? I need your help to explain me how to connect an external database in my app, that will work in a standalone way. If not possible maybe explain me hox to transform my Excel file in .script because it’s the form used by AnyLogic Any other ideas that you may have are welcomed !

Comment: This is a Professional feature only afaik (i.e. Excel access from compiled models). Do you have a Professional license? (You should since you develop models for clients :) )

Answer (score 1):

If you setup your database to refresh on model start, it will also work for compiled (exported) models (if you use the Professional version):
[image]